# how to fix "Error Connection Timed Out Error" of a codeigniter website on a godaddy server?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have uploaded a basic codeigniter website on godaddy server without any database connection. In the config file base url is set to the domain name, index_page is blank & uri_protocol is set to request_uri. I also have the .htaccess file with the code but not sure what to do in it. Here what should i do to remove this error?

I have tried playing with the base url and uri_protocol and also made changes to the .htaccess file but no help either.

My .htaccess code -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: give me domain name.

Comment: http://yourtake.in

Comment: Try this,
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|woff|eot|ttf|svg|css|js|resources|robots\.txt)

Comment: i tried with this code but its saying 'connection timed out' and in localhost its gives me an internal error..

Comment: i found the domain was pointing to a different server so have got it updated will check with your code once activated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have your `/folder/app/.htaccess` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine on    
    RewriteBase /folder/app/    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>
```

then in `/folder/app/application/config/config.php` you need to have this config:

```
$config['base_url']  = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```